# Copy all records between tables with the exception of a line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a syntax that can copy all records from tables that have the same fields:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '7'
```

So I would like to know how do I keep copying all values ​​except the 'id' field (because him is primary key and auto increment).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack any research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You list the columns:

```
insert into table2(col1, . . . coln)
    select col1, . . ., coln
    from table1
    where id = '7';
```

Under most circumstances, you should list the columns explicitly.  You can run into problems even when tables have the same columns but in a different order.

(The one exception in code that I would write is in a script where `table1` is created from `table2` using `create table as`.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to list all the columns specifically:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE id = '7'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to specify the fields you're copying explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, etc)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, etc 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  id = '7'
```